# Unable to execute examples from Tegra Android Developer Pack 1.0r8

Tags: android, tegra

I just recently downloaded the Tegra Android Developer Pack 1.0r8 on a Windows PC. I am trying to run the NativeBasic and NativeGlobe examples from Eclipse IDE but I can not get it.

I installed `Tegra Android Developer Pack 1.0r8`, then opened Eclipse, updated, created a new android virtual device with the following specs:

- Android 2.3.3 - Api Level 10
- SD Card: 1024 mb
- Resolution: 1280 x 800
- Camera support: yes
- Device ram size: 512
- GPU emulation: yes

The problem is that when I do `Package Explorer>NativeBasic>Run As>Android application`, it opens the emulator and when it tries to load `NativeBasic`, the application crashes, showing the following error:

```
05-26 03:12:08.057: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nvidia.devtech.NativeBasic/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: native_basic
```